# Node error: Can't set headers after they are sent. (multiple async requests)

Tags: node.js

I know this type of question has been posted many times. I have read the responses and understand that this is probably due to something I am doing wrong with the timing of the asynchronous requests to widget.save. But I fail to see what exactly it is I am doing wrong.

I have code that saves multiple widgets one by one. The error I get is:

```
[2019-12-20T21:52:18.531Z] res.headersSent: false
POST /widget/ 200 147.460 ms - 276
[2019-12-20T21:52:18.536Z] res.headersSent: false
POST /widget/ 200 139.446 ms - 276
[2019-12-20T21:52:18.538Z] res.headersSent: false
POST /widget/ 200 157.136 ms - 276
[2019-12-20T21:52:18.544Z] res.headersSent: false
POST /widget/ 200 149.833 ms - 276
[2019-12-20T21:52:18.546Z] res.headersSent: false
POST /widget/ 200 153.966 ms - 276
[2019-12-20T21:52:18.627Z] res.headersSent: true
_http_outgoing.js:491
    throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');
```

The first few requests are successful, but then it fails. I can see that the res.headersSent is true right before the failure, but why would this be? My code is as follows:

frontend:

```
_.each(widgets, function (widget) {
    widget.save(widget.changedAttributes(),
              {patch: true,
               success: function (widget) {
                   // report on success
               },
               error: function (data, response, options) {
                   // report error
               }
              }
    );
});
```

node.js router:

```
router.post('/widget/', function(req, res) {
    widgets.post(req, function (response, status){
      console.log('res.headersSent: ' + res.headersSent);
      res.status(status).send(response);
    });
});
```

widget.post function

```
function post (req, res) {
    var values = req.body;
    values.stamp_user_id = req.cookies.user_id;
    db.post(table_name, values, function (result, status) {
      res(result, status);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for `widgets.post()`?  It seems like the problem may be there.  Does it ever call it's callback more than once?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added this to the question.

Comment: Can `db.post()` call its callback more than once?  There's no clear issue in the code you've shown us so far.

Comment: It seems another possibility is that somewhere below the code you've shown us so far, there is a concurrency issue when multiple `db.post()` operations are in process at around the same time, the wrong callback gets called for some of them, causing it to be a 2nd time it's called and some other callback perhaps never gets called.

Comment: @jfriend007 You have definitely helped me by confirming that the code I have shown you seems OK. I will look into db.post().